# C++ thread writes continuously and read at unknown time

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am trying to get the following scenario to work, but have not been successful so far.

I have 2 threads, a worker (that writes) and a reader.
The worker continuously modifies the values of a class "someClassToModify".

The Reader makes a read access every x seconds (unknown) and reads the current state of the class **someClassToModify**.

How do I make sure that the Reader reads **someClassToModify** immediately, without delay, when it "wants" to and the Worker continues immediately afterwards ?

What is important here is that the reader always gets immediate access when it needs it to take a "snapshot" of **someClassToModify**  .

At the moment, the Writer seems to be always "faster", and sometimes several more "Writes" are made before it is the reader's turn. That is, the reader then does not get the actual value that he wanted.

Example:

Work
Work
Work
Work
**Read**
Work
Work
**Read**
Work
Work
Work
Work
**Read**
....

```
SomeClass someClassToModify; //Class to modify and read

std::thread Worker([this] { 

  while(true) {

// work work work (write)
// modify  someClassToModify
  }

}).detach();



std::thread Reader([this] { 

  while(true) {

//at an unknown time (random) read value from someClassToModify

  }

}).detach();
```

thanks for your help here

Comment: It looks like you should take a look at `std::atomic`, `std::mutex`, `std::lock_guard`, `std::unique_lock` and `std::condition_variable` and see what fits.

Comment: Make sure you understand what a data race is, and then think about how to make sure your code doesn't have any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, first of all you should note that threads switch at random. That means that worker can do something multiple times before even a single reader gets chance to do anything.
Second thing is that reader can access function and for example come to 3rd line and then the context switch happens. You want to avoid that.

The way to avoid that is by using lock or semaphore.
That means that your class `someClassToModify` method should disable context switch while reading. It doesnt need to have anything special for explicit switch as it will sleep afterwards for X seconds and during that time the modifier will work.
You should check [std::lock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock).

Basically you would want something like this, wrap this inside your class

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>
#include<mutex>
#include <chrono>
int i = 0;
int x = 1000;
//this is mutex for waiting
std::mutex myLock;
void read() {
    while (true) {
        //you lock the function, so it will not change context
        myLock.lock();
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
        std::cout << "reader" << std::endl;
        //once it is finish you can unlock it
        myLock.unlock();
        //wait for x miliseconds
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(x));
    }
}
void write() {
    while (true) {
        //writer also has lock so you dont end up with bad values on i
        myLock.lock();
        i++;
        std::cout << "writer" << std::endl;
        myLock.unlock();
    }
}
int main() {
    std::thread th1(read);
    std::thread th2(write);
    th1.join();
    th2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `std::lock_guard` as a safer, RAII alternative to using `lock` and `unlock` - *do* be careful with how you scope it, though.  See https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ZDhIBQAAQBAJ&pg=PT319&lpg=PT319&dq=std::lock_guard+meyers&source=bl&ots=60WLhMYvU7&sig=ACfU3U2UZt2oFpvypULB6qBxvSfSK9BbVg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiOwpmfjpjxAhWOGBQKHRoXDkUQ6AEwCHoECBUQAw#v=onepage&q=std%3A%3Alock_guard%20meyers&f=false

Also see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard

Comment: yes. this could be better but sleep should go before locking the function then. As lock_guard unlocks it when it goes out of scope

Comment: Always keep the scope of locks to the absolute minimum.  Also note `std::endl` performs a flush so it's not efficient to have it at the end of two consecutive lines.

Comment: @DusanTodorovic That you can solve by adding an extra scope where the mutex lives.

Comment: @DusanTodorovic thank you for the explanation. But isnt it in theroy possible that the write() method will always be "faster" and so the read() method never would acquire the lock ? 

What if its a loop from 1 to 1000 and i want the reader to read the value if it is exactly 500?

Comment: @DvyHrnsch well it doesn't matter which one is faster as its 2 threads, they get processor time and random. In theory you could have 1000 reads before one write or vice versa. Can you explain to me what you mean by read would never acquire lock? 
If you want to read value and 500, put one if statement and thats it.

Comment: @DusanTodorovic hi, what i mean is:

Lets say we have an int value which is counted from 1 to 1000 by Thread A
and Thread B is reading like:

while(true)
lock mutex
  if(value==500)
  print out: value
unlock mutex

when im executing this programm 100 times, its possible that "print out" value will never be executed as its possible that the Reader nerver locks the mutex right ?

Comment: @DvyHrnsch Well the threads execute at random. So it can happen like this
Incrementer executes : value 498
Reader executes : reads 498 ->does nothing
Reader executes : reads 498 ->does nothing
Incrementer exectues : value 499
Reader executes : reads 499 ->does nothing
Reader executes : reads 499 ->does nothing
Reader executes : reads 499 ->does nothing
Incrementer exectues : value 500
Incrementer exectues : value 501
Reader executes : reads 501 ->does nothing